# What is a reliable way to determine which shared library will be loaded across linux platforms?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shared-libraries

I need to find out which library will be loaded given in the information returned from /sbin/ldconfig.  I came up with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(dirname $(/sbin/ldconfig -p | awk "/$1/ {print \$4}" | head -n 1))
```

Running this results with:

```
$ whichlib libGL.so
/usr/X11R6/lib
```

This a two part question:

1. Will this produce a reliable result across platform?
2. Is there a slicker way to parse the output of ldconfig?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Why don't you use ldd? It always shows you how it will link together the process.

Comment: I'm using this as input to set my LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  The program is not built yet so I can't use ldd.

Answer (score 1):

There're several ways the library is loaded by executeable:
 1.

1. Using $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. Using ld cache
3. Libary with full path compiled into binary (-rpath gcc flag)

You're using option 2, while option 1 and 3 are not considered.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what exactly you're doing you may want to run `ldd` directly on the executable you're planning to run rather than the general case `ldconfig`.

Since you asked, you could write your script like this:

```
dirname "$(/sbin/ldconfig -p | awk "\$1 == "$1" {print \$4; exit}")"
```

It's a little more precise and has one less pipe. Also `echo $(cmd)` is redundant; you can just write `cmd`.

Comment: Your version doesn't accept a command-line argument. In the OP's, `$1` is a Bash argument and `\$4` is an awk field. In yours, `$1` and `$4` are both awk fields and the lib being searched for is hard-coded.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I hard coded it when testing on the command-line.

Comment: Just a reminder, don't use ldd on untrusted code: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/ldd-arbitrary-code-execution/